# VC++ cl.exe -- DLL not found

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, compiler-construction

I added the `bin` directory of the VS2010 (not SP1) C++ compiler to my `PATH` variable on Windows XP.  When i try to run it, it tells me that a DLL was not found.
I added this line to my `PATH`:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin;
```

Update: it still fails when I `cd` to the bin directory above, and then run the compiler

[image: screenshot]

Can you help me out?

Comment: Note: in most message boxes you can press Ctrl-C to get the text of the message box onto the clipboard - that way you don't have to go through the trouble of posting an image.

Comment: @Michael Burr Thanks, will remember that ;)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Run the VS command prompt shortcut or the batch file it points to, such as:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" x86
```

to set up an appropriate environment including the path.

By the way, `mspdb100.dll` lives in `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE`.  But run the shortcut/batch file anyway - it does more than set up the correct path.

Comment: thanks that worked for me too! Would you use "x64" for a 64bit computer?

Comment: @Timothy: Either "x86" or "x64" will set up a build environment on a 64-bit OS. You'd use "x64" if you want to *build* a 64-bit executable.

Answer (score 7):

add *Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE* to your Path variable, than close cmd prompt and open it. now it will work.

Answer (score 1):

Running the VS command prompt takes care of setting up the environment. Also, ensure that you are running the command prompt as an admin.

Answer (score 0):

Installing Visual Studio 2010 SP1 C++ Compiler Setup fixed this issue for me. Visual Studio 2010 SP1 C++ Compiler install

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue when I tried to run a 32 bit exe I built, on a 64 bit machine.

**"mspdb100.dll couldn't be found by cl.exe "**

Visual Studio 2010(the version I currently use)  builds a 32 bit exe by Default.To create a 64 bit executable, just change the setting from Win32 to x64 in the dropdown box at the top of VS and build.This will build for you a 64 bit executable and solve your problem.