# QT Creator won't work

Tags: qt, qt-creator

I tried creating a new project, opening a few old ones but it won't seem to work on my computer and I don't get it. I have got MC Visual Studio 2012 installed and it works as asual but QT Creator is constantly giving me this error message that I think means that something is wrong with the compiler.

```
'cl' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
jom: C:\build-test-Desktop_Qt_5_2_1_MSVC2012_64bit-Debug\Makefile.Debug [debug\main.obj] Error 1
jom: C:\build-test-Desktop_Qt_5_2_1_MSVC2012_64bit-Debug\Makefile [debug] Error 2
12:53:56: The process "C:\Qt\Qt5.2.1\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project test (kit: Desktop Qt 5.2.1 MSVC2012 64bit)
When executing step 'Make'
```

Can anybody explain me how I can fix it ? ( I read somewhere that the reason is that my user folders name is written in cyryllic characters, but is really a pain in the ass to change the name of that folder so I hope that that is not the reason ^^""  )

Comment: it does sound like path problem, So if the PATH is having all necessary paths defined, then uts likely the 'special character' problem you already identified

Comment: Thank you.  One more thing, can I by any chance fix this without creating another user specifically for using QT Creator ?)

Comment: Probably duplicate of [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8800361/cl-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command). You may also find the answer here [(CL not recognized)](https://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/23977)

Comment: Try removing QtCreator and reinstalling it.

Answer (score 0):

I worked around this problem by starting Qt creator from an Qt command prompt, and within that command prompt I run vcvarsall.bat located in "Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC"
So it is a path related problem.

Running Qt Creator 3.0 and VS 10 on Windows 8.1.