# I can't use cl.exe even though I installed C++ workload with Visual Studio

Tags: c++, cl.exe

I'm trying to compile a CPP file with using cl.exe. I selected the C++ workload when downloading Visual Studio. I'm getting this when I try to use it: "'cl.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.". I'm using developer command prompt. I just changed the installation directory at the first and I didn't change anything. Can anyone help me?

Comment: That error happens because ```cl``` isn't in your path. Add it to the path.

Comment: I'm really new on this subject can you please tell me how can I add it?

Comment: From within Visual Studio, select `Tools\Command Line` and then either `Developer Command Prompt` or `Developer PowerShell` and then try `cl`.

Comment: Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8800422/5821185) and follow the instructions.

Comment: @TedLyngmo that didn't work. still the same error.

Comment: Perhaps you need to run such a command in your ```cmd.exe``` in order to set INCLUDE, LIB, and PATH environment variables. ```C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\VC\vcvarsall.bat```

Comment: @cihan Odd... Does it open a window saying `** Visual Studio 2022 Developer Command Prompt v17.9.0-pre.2.0` if you select the `Developer Command Prompt`?

Comment: @TedLyngmo now I fix it. I had to download Desktop Development With C++ Workload too.  after that it worked.

Comment: Oh, so the advice is "Don't forget to install the C++ compiler!".  :-)