# mspdb140.dll is missing from your computer

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll

I am trying to check if the visual studio compiler exist in my path. I have add vc/bin dir to the system environment path. When I open a windows console terminal I try to call cl.exe from the console. I am receiving the following message:

> The program cant start because mspdb140.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem.

What exactly is this message stands about? I tried to followed the instructions from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6476607/vc-cl-exe-dll-not-found), I run the bat file, (furthremore I add manually the dll dir in the path). However I am receiving the same message.

Comment: `cl.exe` links dynamically to `mspdb140.dll`, as evidenced by running `dumpbin` on it. The error means the file cannot be found by the Windows PE loader; what path exactly have you added to your PATH? It should be `<Program Files>\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin`.

Comment: Have you tried run "Developer Command prompt..." from `Visual Studio Tools` Start menu? This will automatically set all required environment variables.

Comment: It just isn't enough.  Being able to properly compile takes a wholeheckofalot more environment variable hacking.  The values of the INCLUDE and LIB variables are critical for example.  That's why there's a .bat file to get it done for you, run vcvarsall.bat.  Pass the architecture you want to target, default is x86.  Usually done automagically by a shortcut named something like "Visual Studio Command Prompt", not sure what they name it these days.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I have add vc/bin dir to the system environment path

That certainly isn't enough.  Unclear what else you are doing.  There are a wholeheckofalot more environment variables that need to be hacked correctly to allow proper compiling and linking.  The values of INCLUDE and LIB are critical for example.

There is a .bat file that takes care of it, vc/vcvarsall.bat in the VS install directory.  You pass the architecture you want to target, default is x86.  Be sure you use the CALL statement if you use a .bat file yourself and that you in fact see the variables being set correctly with, say, SET INCLUDE.  Watch out for a broken PATH variable, a very common scourge on programmers' machines.  Usually corrupted by a wonky installer.

The VS installer creates shortcuts to run this .bat file.  Used to be named "Visual Studio Command Prompt", might be "Developer Command Prompt".  Got pretty muddy since Windows 8.

I personally just an entry in the VS Tools menu.  Very handy.  Use Tools > External Tools > Add button.  And fill out the dialog similar to this:

- Title = Command Prompt
- Command = cmd.exe
- Arguments = /k ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat"" x86
- Initial directory = $(ProjectDir)

Tweak 14.0 to the version number of your VS version, that's VS2015.  VS2013 = 12.0, VS2012 = 11.0, VS2010 = 10.0